# unity container class with different lifetimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container, observer-pattern

I'm currently doing the following, inside my `UnityConfig.cs` which get's called by the UnityMvcActivator at `App_Start`:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserDal, UserDal>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

I'm also doing this:

```
container.RegisterType<IEmailObserver, EmailObserver>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

I should've mentioned that `IUserDal` is in the constructor of `IEmailObserver`:

```
public EmailObserver(IUserDal userDal);
```

now I want to start the `EmailObserver` instance when the application starts, so I have this:

```
`DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

container.Resolve<IEmailObserver>();//this line fails
```

The error message I get is:

`Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request. Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate synchronization context.`

I'm trying to implement the [Observer Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern) but I want to use Unity to register my observers and initialize them when the app starts.

Comment: You're probably calling `container.Resolve()` too early (when there's no `HTTPContext` available yet). Where exactly are you calling it? Is it part of the code that's invoked during `Application_Start()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check EmailObserver constructor - all types from there should be singletones too, I think.

Comment: I have a feeling that's the issue but see my edit, the `IUserDal` is `PerRequest` and the `IEmailObserver` is `ContainerControlled`

Comment: so UserDal should be singletone or EmailObserver should be per request.

Comment: this is what I wanted to make sure, so basically in unity a class and all of its dependencies have to share the same lifetime manager?

Comment: nope. But when you want to create EmailObserver without any request (as singletone), Unity tried to resolve all dependences and found, that it should create UserDal as constructor parameter. While creating UserDal, Unity noticed that there are no request at this time and cant create UserDal and EmailObserver as well.

Comment: Singletones CANT use instances in constructor parameters, which should be created per request, because singletone constructor called once during application lifecycle. It is impossible to update UserDal instance insilde EmailObserver each request using yours implementation

Comment: if you change UserDal to singletone and EmailObserver to per request, it should work, because per-request instances CAN use singletones in constructor parameter, but NOT vice versa